# How can I pass cursor and set focus on a Userform textbox in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

In below program, I receive this error: Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': Unspecified error. by highlight this code: `txtStartDate.SetFocus` in this line: `If txtStartDate.Text = "" Then txtStartDate.SetFocus`

```
Private Sub txtTimeUnit_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

If IsError(Application.Match(txtTimeUnit.Text, Range("intTable[Units]"), 0)) Then
    lblStatusBar = "Please correct value."
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

lblStatusBar = vbNullString

Range("CToDate").Value = txtTimeUnit.Text

If txtStartDate.Text = "" Then txtStartDate.SetFocus
If txtEndDate.Text = "" Then txtEndDate.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me about this error and passing text box focus (Cursor) to another text box?

Comment: Please not that I entered correct value in initial text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
If txtStartDate.Text = "" Then txtStartDate.SetFocus
```

by

```
If txtStartDate.Text = "" Then
    txtStartDate.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: This work, but when I write: `If txtStartDate.Text = vbNullString Then
        txtTimeUnit = vbNullString
        txtStartDate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If` because of `txtTimeUnit=vbnullstring` line I receive above error.

Comment: Why would you change the code? You had a specific question and I gave you a specific answer "in regards" to that question

Comment: Also BTW your code which you mentioned in the previous comment and also posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878425/made-null-textbox-and-set-focus-on-another) works for me

Comment: I don't change the code. I reached a new problem in use, and ask in comment of your answer and new question in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878425/made-null-textbox-and-set-focus-on-another)

Comment: yes i know. I already commented there :) Your code works for me

Comment: @Downvoter: I know it is not mandatory but I would like to know why the downvote. Perhaps I can learn from you? Or maybe you actually do not have the B.A.L.L.S to comment like I do whenever I downvote?

Comment: @MGae2M: From where I can see it, I already answered your question in this post. Regarding your other post, I will carry the conversation there :)

Comment: Regarding and thanks a lot for your answer, that help and solve my problem at first, I was Upvote you. and this code with `txtTimeUnit=vbNullString` not work for me.