# Made null textbox and set focus on another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using code below, for check another textbox value when exiting initial textbox and if it null, making initial one null and set focus on final textbox.

But i give this error: Run-time error'-2147467259(80004005)': Unspecific error.

when i made comment this line (`txtTimeUnit = vbNullString`), macro code works correctly.

whats the problem of that line's command and please help me correcting code.

```
Private Sub txtTimeUnit_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If txtStartDate.Text = vbNullString Then
        txtTimeUnit = vbNullString
        txtStartDate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `txtTimeUnit.Text = vbNullString` - you can't set the control itself to `vbNulLString`.

Comment: Your answer was not right. `txtTimeUnit=vbnullstring` is true code and works. the problem is in `txtStartDate.SetFocus` line, so been highlight after debugging error. if I move `Exit Sub` before that line, macro works and no error happens, but I need set focus on txtStartDate textbox.

Comment: Your comment on Siddarth's answer on your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871013/how-can-i-pass-cursor-and-set-focus-on-a-userform-textbox-in-vba) said that the `txtTimeUnit=vbnullstring` was the problem line. Also you say that commenting out that line makes the code work - so the indication from your question is that is the problem.

Comment: As I wrote in this question, `txtTimeUnit=vbNullSrting` highlight and shown as error line after I click on debug in error form. Thus the problem is not in that line you tell in your first comment, and by replacing `Exit Sub` line before `txtStartDate.SetFocus`, macro not encounter error and here I need SetFocus on txtStartDate textbox. (As I asked in that comment you tell)

Comment: Your above code works for me

Comment: So, how would me made mistake so trow that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said your code works. Here is an example

```
Private Sub txtTimeUnit_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If txtStartDate.Text = vbNullString Then
        txtTimeUnit.Text = vbNullString
        txtStartDate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The only way it will not work is when there is another piece of code which is setting the `Cancel = True`. For example

```
Private Sub txtTimeUnit_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If IsError(Application.Match(txtTimeUnit.Text, Range("intTable[Time Unit]"), 0)) Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

    If txtStartDate.Text = vbNullString Then
        txtTimeUnit.Text = vbNullString
        txtStartDate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

To prevent such kind of errors you can use a `Boolean` Variable

```
Dim boolOnce As Boolean

Private Sub txtTimeUnit_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If boolOnce = False Then
        boolOnce = True
        If IsError(Application.Match(txtTimeUnit.Text, Range("intTable[Time Unit]"), 0)) Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Else
        boolOnce = False
    End If

    If txtStartDate.Text = vbNullString Then
        txtTimeUnit.Text = vbNullString
        txtStartDate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```